# How to set a time-out for File.Create method on network drive?

Tags: c#, file, io, networkstream

I have a requirement in my application where I need to create the file in a network drive, 
but when file creation in progess if network disconnected application hangs **for a while** and throws an exception.

Is there any way we can set time-out for `File.Create`?

Comment: This is almost always a mistake.  You're only optimizing your code to fail faster, it doesn't help the user get the job done.  Worse, you are adding a new failure mode: not waiting long enough.  Now its your problem, not the LAN administrator's.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that can be used to implement time-out manually:

```
var fileCreatingThread = new Thread(...);
fileCreatingThread.Start();
if (fileCreatingThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) { /* Worked correctly */}
else
{
    // time-out
}
```

Comment: 1) This doesn't cope with any exceptions the other thread might throw. 2) Killing threads is not nice.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, do you mean that there is different approach to this or that I should write production-ready code here with exception handling, logging, etc.?

Comment: I was pointing out the issued with this code so the OP can take care of them when he creates his production code. And I wouldn't kill the thread. I'd just leave it running and let it naturally die once it is finished with its job. Killing won't work anyways since `Thread.Abort` can't interrupt unmanaged code. And any stronger method of killing makes the state of your process undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to configure the network timeout for File.Create(). It seems likely that this is built into the framework or more likely the operating system itself.

Can you try to establish a network connection before you create the file? Maybe ping the target or open a socket? If this fails, you know not to try to create the file. If it succeeds, there's a good chance the file creation will go through unless there's a security issue.